# Multiple select get Selected options in order selected

Tags: javascript, select

i have a multiple select like the following

```
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

that i have implemented chosen plugin on i have an onchange listener that adds selected elements to an array like so

```
$("#cars").change(function () {
 
    var selected = [];
    for (var option of document.getElementById('cars').options) {
        if (option.selected) {
            selected.push(option.value);
        }
    }
    console.log(selected);


 
});
```

however in which ever option i select the items they always end up arranging themselves in the order they are in the multiple select
for example by selecting the values Volvo , Audi, Saab in that order results in the following array

```
Array [ "Volvo" ]
Array [ "Volvo", "Audi" ]
Array(3) [ "Volvo", "Saab", "Audi" ]
```

Is there a way that i can add elements in a multiple select to an array in the order which they were selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get the same order of the `selected` array because you create it each time you run your `onChange` function. So the solution would be to make it a global variable. When you do that, your array won't be empty at the second choice tho, so you have to take care of removing items from it.
Here's some code

```js
 var selected = [];
$("#cars").change(function () {
    for (var option of document.getElementById('cars').options) {
            var value = option.value;
        if (option.selected) {
                if(selected.indexOf(value) < 0){//we only add element if it's not present in the array
                selected.push(value);
            }
        }else{
            if(selected.indexOf(value) >= 0){ //we only remove item if it is present
                selected.splice(selected.indexOf(value),1)
          }
        }
    }
    console.log(selected);


 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```